# TCL package name from proc name

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to work out the package a proc belongs to so I can validate the package version

Say I have package

```
some::package 1.0
```

Which has a proc

```
some::package::some_proc
```

given some::package::some_proc i'd like to be able to get 1.0

I can't guarantee that the namespace has the same name as the package it belongs to

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Technically you cannot do this without providing your own version of `package require`. Namespaces and packages and files in Tcl are not linked, like they are in Python or Java.

If you know that all procs are statically defined (e.g. no dynamic code generation), you could replace `package require` with your own version and enumerate all procs before and after the call and put the names in some registry.

What are you trying to validate?

If you want to validate some kind of API, you could look at the [pluginmgr](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/pluginmgr/pluginmgr.html) package in Tcllib.

Comment: Hi, thats an interesting approach, I have done something similar in my pkgIndex.tcl. I have a tcl rpc server that i've written that sits on top of a massive library of legacy tcl. I wanted to validate that the pkg versions were consistent. Hence trying to work out what package was loaded given the proc name. I'll have a look at pluginmgr. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`namespace current`:](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/namespace.htm#M7)

```
% namespace eval some::package {
    proc some_proc {} { puts [namespace current] }
}
% some::package::some_proc
::some::package
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks though I can't guarantee that the package is named the same as the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Conventionally, but *not universally*, you get the name of a package from the name of the namespace containing the command in question:

```
set pkg [namespace qualifiers [namespace which $theCommand]]
# Be aware, this produces the empty string for global commands
```

However, not all packages do this; some older packages do not put their public commands into a namespace (for historical/back-compatibility reasons). In that case, searching the documentation is about the only thing you can do.

Once you've got the package name, you can determine the currently-loaded version of the package with `package present`:

```
set version [package present $pkg]
```

This only works if the package has previously been `package require`d, of course. You can also use `package versions` to determine what other versions of the package are available in your environment; though Tcl will only load one version of a package into an interpreter context, you can have many different ones installed without (necessarily) having problems.

Comment: Note that loading many versions at once can get you into real problems; this can happen with Java library JARs in an environment like Tomcat or OSGi, and it is catastrophically complex to debug when it happens. (It almost works, except stuff ends up giving errors that appear totally nonsensical like “can't handle `foo.Bar`: expected `foo.Bar` instead”.)

Comment: Hi, I've had a play and it does work for those packages which have the same name as the namespace. Though not if they differ. I'm going to look at the idea mentioned below regarding re-writing package require to store info about the package as I load it. Thanks for your help